# Use FISH to connect through jump server in KDE Dolphin

Tags: ssh, kde, plasma, sftp, fish

I need to access the files in a server that could only be connected using a jump server. I am able to SSH into it using

> ssh -J user1@jumpserver_ip user2@server_ip

How can I use fish protocol in dolphin browser to view the files in the server through jump server.

Thank you

Comment: Any news on that?

Comment: No info yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. My solution was to define the jump point in  ~/.ssh/config, see here: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host